# Karma issue Javascript import SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine, gulp-karma

I am trying to run this spec and I got this error:
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

But as you see I have the import on top, so there's could be another reason for this?

ng-form-builder.spec.js

```
import angular from "angular";
import mocks from "angular-mocks";
import "src/ng-form-builder.js";

var inject = mocks.inject;
var module = mocks.module;

describe('ng-form-builder', function () {
  var scope, $compile, $rootScope, element;

  function createDirective(template) {
    var elm;

    elm = angular.element(template);
    angular.element(document.body).prepend(elm);
    $compile(elm)(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    return elm;
  }

  beforeEach(module('ngSanitize', 'peoplewareDo.ng-form-builder'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $compile = _$compile_;
  }));
```

ng-form-builder.js

```
(function () {

'use strict';

angular.module('peoplewareDo.ng-form-builder', []).directive('ngFormBuilder', function () {
   ....
});

// coffeescript's for in loop
var __indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) {
        for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (i in this && this[i] === item) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    };

angular.module('peoplewareDo.ng-form-builder', []).directive('ngFormField', function($http, $compile) {
...

});

}());
```

console log

```
[vns@localhost ng-form-builder]$ gulp test
[15:01:07] Using gulpfile ~/workspace/ng-form-builder/gulpfile.js
[15:01:07] Starting 'clean'...
[15:01:07] Starting 'scripts'...
[15:01:07] Finished 'scripts' after 65 ms
[15:01:07] Starting 'styles'...
[15:01:07] Starting 'jshint-test'...
[15:01:07] Starting 'karma'...
[15:01:07] Finished 'clean' after 205 ms
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.37 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Firefox
[15:01:08] Finished 'jshint-test' after 346 ms
[15:01:08] Finished 'styles' after 500 ms
[15:01:08] Starting 'build'...
[15:01:08] Finished 'build' after 6.5 μs
INFO [Firefox 45.0.0 (Fedora 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket saObD8MsBt0Hw9swPwC5 with id 21261564
Firefox 45.0.0 (Fedora 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
  at /home/vns/workspace/ng-form-builder/test/ng-form-builder.spec.js:1
[15:01:11] 'karma' errored after 4.06 s
[15:01:11] Error: 1
    at formatError (/usr/lib/node-v5.7.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node-v5.7.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:195:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:182:7)
```

Comment: `import "src/ng-form-builder.js";` ? Is that valid ?

Comment: Can you post the content of `src/ng-form-builder.js` file?

Comment: I also thought on that but I commented out and got the same issue, so yes it is valid.

Comment: Maybe `module` is causing you trouble. Try changing the variable's name perhaps

Comment: @OmriAharon I also tried that, same issue

Comment: Ok I think I know. The code looks like it's run on Firefox, which does not support ES6 natively, and it does not seem you use babel to transpile to ES5.

Comment: @OmriAharon ok, so how do I do that, any tutorial?? so I need to change the karma.conf.js I suppose, right??

Comment: This might help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel If not try to google some more, haven't done babel + gulp myself. But basically you just need to run the babel task on your files and then consume the generated ES5 files instead of your original ES6 ones

Comment: @OmriAharon I did setup babel with karma but getting another issue   ReferenceError: System is not defined
  at /home/vns/workspace/ng-form-builder/test/ng-form-builder.spec.js:3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110638/discussion-between-victor-sosa-and-omri-aharon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Firefox, which is the browser that this code is executed in as can be seen here:

```
INFO [Firefox 45.0.0 (Fedora 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket saObD8MsBt0Hw9swPwC5 with id 21261564
Firefox 45.0.0 (Fedora 0.0.0) ERROR
```

Does not support ES6 completely. Transpiling from ES6 to ES5 is required in order for this code to run.

Comment: You may want to check this other issue that I have; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939435/karma-issue-javascript-referenceerror-system-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

import is the ES2015 feature and currently many browsers wont support this. Use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)- a javascript compiler which compiles from EC2015 to ES5.